# Android - open firefox intent url in new tab

Tags: java, android, firefox, android-intent

I have a view with few buttons, each buttons suppose to open a different url in firefox, but instead after one of the buttons clicked and the url opens in firefox, all the other buttons just opens firefox but not navigating to their url.

this is the code I am using for the intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
i.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.mozilla.firefox", "org.mozilla.firefox.App"));
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putBoolean("new_window", true); //suppose to set the new window
i.putExtras(b);
i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
startActivity(i);
```

How should I code it to open each button click on new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Intent.ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
openpage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("your url")));

            }
        });
```

Should work